# Query timeout in MS SQL for Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, connection-timeout

I have a macro in Excel connecting to MS SQL, checking some counts and writing in my Excel sheet. It was working properly but it is not working now. I have an error code like this:

> Run-time error -2147217871 Query Timeout Expired

My time out value is `960` but it showing me this problem.

How can I solve this problem?

I am sharing code with you:

```
Sub GetDataFromADO()
    'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    'Open Connection'
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<server>;User ID=<id>;Password=<pass>;"
    'For Timeout'
        Application.ODBCTimeout = 960
        objMyConn.Open
    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        'Set Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        currentDate = Worksheets("RUN").Range("A1").Value
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cnt = 0
        currentSheet = "LegalInsCrawling" 'Seq
        cell = Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Value
        Do
            cnt = cnt + 1
            cell = Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Offset(cnt).Value
        Loop Until cell = "" Or cell = CDate(currentDate)
        Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Offset(cnt).Value = currentDate
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "<mssql query>"
        objMyCmd.Execute
        'Open Recordset'
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd
        Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("B1").Offset(cnt).CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        objMyRecordset.Close
        '------
        cnt = 0
        currentSheet = "LegalInsCrawling" 'HomePageCrawlingCount
        cell = Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Value
        Do
            cnt = cnt + 1
            cell = Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Offset(cnt).Value
        Loop Until cell = "" Or cell = CDate(currentDate)
        Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("A1").Offset(cnt).Value = currentDate
         objMyCmd.CommandText = "<mssql query>"
        objMyCmd.Execute
        'Open Recordset'
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd
        Worksheets(currentSheet).Range("D1").Offset(cnt).CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        objMyRecordset.Close
```

Comment: I guess `<mssql query>` is taking too long to run. I suggest you try and optimise it. A good idea is to paste it into SQL Server Management Studio, press CTRL-L and see if it suggests indexes.

Comment: Does the error appear after 16 minutes? If your query takes too long, you should post *the query*, not the VBA macro. Nothing you do in the macro is going to make the query run faster. While you *can* change the timout, this won't make the query go faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Actually i have more than 10 query in just one excel. When macro is working, ten or more query is starting. Do i have another solution in excel?

Comment: The error would be raised on _one_ of those ten queries. Which one?